# EV3 Folder not appearing on Windows

Tags: ev3

I am attempting to load a UF2 file into an EV3 robot, however when I plug everything in, nothing appears. Windows recognises that a device has been plugged in, and it even appears in the Device Manager, however it doesn't point to a file folder.

Comment: Please tell me which kind of windows platform you are trying to set it up on

Comment: Please ask the other question in a separate question, so that you can get separate answers for them :)

Comment: @zovits I think it would be a dupe if that was done, I recall similar question but I'm not sure

Comment: Please add more details, jeremy. How are you "loading uf2 file"? How are you making that file type? Did you do anything with the EV3 drive when you plugged it into the computer? More details are needed to solve your problem.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Makecode. I wrote some simple code as a test, and downloaded it as the UF2 file. The EV3 drive is not appearing in the Windows File Explorer when I plug it in, however Windows recognises it is there.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you mean the EV3 drive is not visible in the file explorer when you look? It may be the F drive or another drive with a differnet letter and it should be named EV3.

Answer (score 1):

This is from https://makecode.mindstorms.com/troubleshoot

Check that you have the newest firmware; on the EV3 brick:

1. Go all the way to the right to the wrench tab
2. Go all the way down to the menu called 'Brick Info'
3. The information dialog that appears should say something like:

   Brick FW: v1.10E

If you have a version which is less than this, then you need to upgrade. Unfortunately, this can only be done from the very buggy EV3 Manager at https://ev3manager.education.lego.com/